# tf.GradientTape() return None

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to calculate the gradient with tf.GradientTape.
When I try to do it using as inputs the loss and Model.variables (tf.keras.Model) the result that returns me in an array of None.
what am I doing wrong?
The tensorflow version I use is 1.9.

```
Model = CubeValModel(TrainingCurves)

LearningRate = 0.0005
TrainOpe = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LearningRate, name="MainTrainingOpe")

for i in range (5):
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        Predictions = tf.nn.softmax(Model.FinalFC, name="SoftmaxPredictions")
        Cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Predictions, labels=TrainingLabels, name="CrossEntropy")
        Loss = tf.reduce_mean(Cross_entropy, name="Loss")
        print (Loss)
        print (Model.variables)
        Gradients = t.gradient(Loss, Model.variables)
        print(Gradients)
```

Outputs:

```
tf.Tensor(0.84878147, shape=(), dtype=float32)

[<tf.Variable 'LayerBlock1/Weights1:0' shape=(1, 3, 1, 3) dtype=float32, numpy=

[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using TensorFlow eager execution, an't you?
If I'm not mistaken, under tf.GradientTape(), You should call the method that computes your model instead of calling one of its member. This computation execution will allow t to figure out which gradients it needs to generate later.
I hope this helps

Comment: Hi, can you specify which method you were talking? The methods I can find for `tf.GradientTape()` are reset(), gradient(), stop)recording(), etc. I didn't understand what do you mean by "one of its members", especially `tf.GradientTape().gradient()` looks same as what the tutorial did. Thank you!

Comment: @Blunt I'm facing this issue

Comment: found any solutions ?